# On animation, part of listview is not showing

Tags: android, listview, layout, android-listview

I have researched the questions thoroughly, but could not yet find the answer. Also, my excuses for my poor english since I am not a native speaker.

The problem: in my android layout we have a status_text with a listview below the status_text. When the status_text is touched, we animate a 'move down' on the status_text and listview so that only the first of the listview row is still on screen. The listview is now still usable.

When the status_text is touched again, we move the status_text and listview up so that the listview uses half of the screen.

The problem we are facing is that during the 'move up' only the first row is animated. After the 'move up'  the other rows suddenly appear.

What we would like to have is a 'move up' where the previously hidden rows slide onto the screen.

The layout: 
We are using this layout (slightly simplified to focus on the problem at hand):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_declareren_choose_verzekerden"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- Dummy anchor to put top of listview in the middle of the screen -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/anchor"
        style="@style/anchor_status_container"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    </RelativeLayout>


    <!-- Example image -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/image_description"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/empty" />


    <!-- Clickable text which moves up and down on click -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/status_container"
        style="@style/status_container"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/anchor"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/status_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_sml"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/status_container" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- Listview which moves up and down with the status_container -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/listView_container"
        style="@style/padding_content_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/status_container"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mylistView"
            style="@style/myListviewStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


    <!-- Footer with buttons -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer_button_container"
        style="@style/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_again"
            style="@style/btn_secondary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="@string/opnieuw"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_next"
            style="@style/btn_primary"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the code (again a bit simplified to show only the problem at hand. Some fade-in/out and rotations are removed):

```
   // The code
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view)
   {
      int viewId = view.getId();
      if (viewId == R.id.status_container)
      {
         // Someone clicked the text, move the statusbar (and so the listview) up or down
         if (this.viewIsInUpperPosition)
         {
            startStatusAnimation();
         }
      }
   }

   private void startStatusAnimation()
   {
      if (animationIsRunning)
      {
         return;
      }
      setAnimationIsRunning(animValues.START);

      // 0. Initialisation
      final View statusContainer = (View) getView().findViewById(R.id.status_container);
      final View listContainer = (View) getView().findViewById(R.id.listView_container);
      final ListView listView = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.myListView);
      final View footerButtonContainer = (View) getView().findViewById(R.id.footer_button_container);

      // 1. Calculate distance for animation
      if (toggleViewDistance == 0)
      {
         int listViewContainerHeight = listContainer.getHeight();
         int footerHeight = footerButtonContainer.getHeight();
         int spaceForListView = listViewContainerHeight - footerHeight;
         toggleViewDistance = spaceForListView;
      }

      // 2. Decide if the movement is up or down
      float translationDistance = (viewIsInUpperPosition) ? toggleViewDistance : 0 - toggleViewDistance;

      // 3. Create the animation
      TranslateAnimation yMove = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, translationDistance);
      yMove.setDuration(animValues.ANIMATION_Y_DURATION);
      yMove.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

      // Do here something with scaling and rotating of other objects, not relevant for the question on StackOverflow

      // 4. Actions after animation

      yMove.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
         {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0)
            {
               // Fade de listView in als je van onderen naar boven animeert
               if (!viewIsInUpperPosition)
               {
                  // Do some fading, outside scope of question
               }

               // Create layout after the animation
               RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) statusContainer.getLayoutParams();
               if (viewIsInUpperPosition)
               {
                  // View was previously in upper position, now put the statusbar aligned with the footer
                  params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                  params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, footerButtonContainer.getId());
               }
               else
               {
                  // View was previously in bottom position, so put it under the anchor
                  params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                  params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP, R.id.anchor);
                  }
               }
               statusContainer.setLayoutParams(params); // Set the new layout params

               viewIsInUpperPosition = !viewIsInUpperPosition; 
               setAnimationIsRunning(animValues.END);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0)
            {
               // Empty
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0)
            {
               // empty
            }
         });

      // 5. Start the animation
      statusContainer.startAnimation(yMove);
      listContainer.startAnimation(yMove);
   }
```

Any advice on how to have the rows of the listview 'slide in' on the screen? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. So I am answering my own question in case someone stumbles upon this question.

What needs to be done is that the listview is drawn off-screen. This can be forced by calling the measure- and layout-methods with the off-screen coordinates of the listview.

This fixed it for my code:

```
  // 5a. Draw the listview off-screen
  if (translationDistance < 0)
  {
     // Do this only when the listview is sliding up, e.g. sliding the window in.

     int listViewContainerVerticalPos = listContainer.getTop(); // De positie van de listview

     // The required height of the listview
     int listContainerHeight = (int) Math.abs(translationDistance) + statusContainer.getHeight();

     int measureWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listContainer.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
     int measureHight = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listContainerHeight, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
     listContainer.measure(measureWidth, measureHight);

     listContainer.layout(0, listContainerVerticalPos, listContainer.getMeasuredWidth(), listContainerVerticalPos
           + listContainerHeight);
  }
```